# Protect a PTC from being touched

Tags: polyfuse, heat-protection

I am considering using PTC to protect PS/2 keyboard +5V power line. As it is low probability that there's something wrong will be inserted into the 6-pin mini-DIN connector, IMHO it is not necessary to design more complex electronic protection, and it would be enough to have just PTC to prevent fire development.

However, when PTC is in action, it heats up to 125 C. Imagine there're plastic parts around - specifically ribbon cable, which may be rated for 85 C, hot PTC will melt its isolation and cause even bigger problem.

Is there any mean to physically protect the component (PTC) from the touching anything else (in addition to placing it properly onto the PCB)? Maybe some mesh-type cage solderable to PCB allowing proper ventilation but disabling anything coming in touch with the heating device?

**Update:** thanks for the comments! So let's consider PPTC. There's an inportant note in the Bourns SMD PPTCs ([MF-MSMF](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/54/mfmsmf-772347.pdf)) that they can not be soldered by hand. Considering [MF-R](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/54/mfr-777680.pdf) series - let's say, MF-R020.

**Update:** I have bought MF-R020, with initial resistance of 1.9 Ohms, connected it to 5V, ATX PSU did not get into the protective mode, current through the PPTC after several seconds is about 100 mA. Temperature is hot, but not enough to melt the plastic. After disconnection from the +5V power rails restores value to 2.4 Ohms within a minute, and keyboard keeps working properly. Several stresses seem not degrade the PPTC.

Comment: Totally, totally off subject but for years I've thought it's Johnny Rotten on your miniaturised icon. Now I see it's Doc. Emmett Brown :-)

Comment: @TonyM right :)

Comment: hm, wouldn't a cage of sorts (these probably exist, but I'd just abuse one of these heatsinks that have through-hole prongs), or any other mechanical element, in the end be more costly or complex than say a polyfuse or a overcurrent protection IC?

Comment: I would consider using a **polyfuse** instead of a PTC as a polyfuse also protects but **without getting hot**. Also, the power consumption of a hot PTC would bug me as being a bit "crude design".

Comment: Is there any real risk of a keyboard exceeding a current limit?

Comment: @jonathanjo not keyboard itself, but connecting something custom-made or with mistaken pin connections. And in general it is a good idea to somehow protect power rails going directly out of the chassis to peripherals.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie the information I can find on PPTCs also says that they heat up, but no detailed data on how much they heat is available.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie To be excessively pedantic, polyfuses *do* heat up, just nowhere near as much.